# How to dynamically switch color with Leaflet's pulse icon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

Given my code below, I have added a non-pulsing marker to my map, using [L.icon.pulse](https://github.com/mapshakers/leaflet-icon-pulse/blob/master/src/L.Icon.Pulse.js):

```
m = L.geoJSON(metaFeatures, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var pulsingIcon = L.icon.pulse({
      iconSize: [3, 3],
      color: color,
      fillColor: color,
      animate: false,
    });
    var pulseMarker = L.marker(coordinates, { icon: pulsingIcon });
    return pulseMarker;

    //...
  },
});
```

Later when I wish to change the `animate:false` to `animate:true` and change the color to `red`.

Note: if the marker was:

```
var circle = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
```

I would be able to do: `layer.setStyle({fillColor:'blue'});` and that would solve the problem but since this is a `L.Marker` it cannot be done.

Comment: What are trying to achieve? Toggling your pulsating icon on/off by swapping between a static CircleMarker and a pulse icon? Or changing the size of your pulse icon, like you have done for your CircleMarker?

Comment: @ghybs thank you. I have upgraded my question completely (as I noticed my error). Per you question, I'm trying to change the color and the pulse (of a marker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Leaflet, instances of `L.Marker` don't have any `.setStyle()`, method, but they do have a [`.setIcon()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker-seticon).

Therefore, you can create several instances of `L.Icon` and have your markers use one or the other, e.g.:

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ],
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

var blueIcon = L.icon.pulse({ color: "blue", fillColor: "blue", animate: false});
var redIcon = L.icon.pulse({ color: "red", fillColor: "red", animate: true});

var mymarker = L.marker([0,0], {icon: blueIcon}).addTo(map);

L.DomEvent.on(document.getElementById('change-to-red'), 'click', function(){
  mymarker.setIcon(redIcon);
})
```

```css
#leaflet { min-height: 300px; }
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pulse-icon@0.1.0/src/L.Icon.Pulse.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-pulse-icon@0.1.0/src/L.Icon.Pulse.js"></script>
<div id="leaflet"></div>
<button id='change-to-red'>Change to red!</button>
```

Comment: thank you. I get this error: (index):354 Uncaught TypeError: marker.setIcon is not a function. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ProcolHarum: very probably you are trying to change the icon of something that is not a Marker with icon.

Comment: @IvanSanchez ok I'm on it. I understand your pointer but it's interesting that I can do setStyle and not setIcon. Could it be because I return L.geoJSON?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Got it. Thanks!